# Can't find a way to set the brightness via the terminal

Tags: brightness, xmonad, xbacklight

I recently started using a window manager (XMonad) and am enjoying it. The only issue is I have to reconfigure a lot of the the function keys (volume, brightness, etc) to do what they're supposed to do. I've been able to figure out everything except for the brightness.

All the solutions using xbacklight or xrandr I've found online seem to do absolutely nothing. For instance, `xbacklight -get` gives no output.

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 on a Dell xps 13.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will on the Dell XPS work with the tool [light](https://github.com/haikarainen/light).

You need to compile the software. It is very easy, but you may need to install the developpertools and git before:

```
sudo apt install build-essential git
```

Then you can proceed to downloading and compiling the code. First clone the source code of `light`. Alternatively, you can download the source as a zip file and extract that on your local drive. Here, we use git:

```
git clone https://github.com/haikarainen/light.git
```

Change current directory to the downloaded folder, compile and install:

```
cd light
make
sudo make install
```

Assign following commands to hotkeys to increase or decrease brightness

```
light -A 5 # increase screen brightness
light -U 5 # decrease screen brightness
```

You may need to install

Comment: I have a Dell XPS 13 myself ;)